# Issue with universal motor velocity control by microcontroller

Tags: motor, triac

I'm using the circuit in the picture with a BTB12 600BW snuberless triac to control an universal motor (picked from a old washing machine, 220 VAC, 50 Hz) controlled by an arduino nano in customized PCB I made. At the moment only in "open loop" control.

[image]
As zero crossing I'm using the circuit below, with the output on the emittor side and a 10KOhm pull-down resistor.

https://images.app.goo.gl/VrPu1aej51YPKi3s8

The problem started when I connected the motor and ran the program, as you can see (fixed voltage, 45 VAC):
https://youtu.be/5Q3df7z6ZT0

Setting a fixed or variable (ramp) voltage from arduino, the motor sometime, at a random time, "jump" at a higher velocity then return back to the imposed velocity. It seems that sometimes the triac remains close for some AC cycle before to come back to the normal behaviour, and so on.

The simple code I'm using is here: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1d2r3AmiUaU0wRjiOclEF8eqn1y7RIoIr

Note that the main loop has been purified from Serial and delay() functions to not affect the correct interrupt execution, but the problem is still present.

I passed the code to a friend of mine that have a very similar circuit (he only differ for mounting an R-C snubber on a classic not snuberless triac) and no problem of "jumping" appear to him.

At this point I'm thinking of a problem on the motor's collector. Unfortunately I don't have an oscilloscope. When the jump happen, I'm able to see a little increment in the output voltage (only the transient tail the multimeter is capable to capture).

What do you think about?

To Marko:
Yes, infact I was thinking that the R+C in my case should be used to snubber the optocoupler and not the triac (as suggested in many MOC30XX AN). For now I tried to insert a classic snubber R=100 Ohm and C=100nF on the main TRIAC side and it seems to work well. I solved temporarely but I didn't understand why a "snuberless TRIAC" requires in my case a snubber! Another test i can do is to eliminate the TRIAC snubber and insert an optocoupler snubber to see if the problem is solved the same. Maybe the current R+C I added helps in some way the turn off of the internal MOC triac, not the main triac. As last help, what size do you think I should consider in the R+C OPTO and R+C TRIAC. Currently I used 4W for the 100Ohm resistor (39Ohm in the AN) and 630V for the 100nF capacitor.
[image]

Comment: install snubber. this application can't work without it.

Comment: Marko, I will do it. But just curious why in some similar application they are not used and all work well! All the washing machine makers don't use snubber with a snuberless triac (they use the MOV as for IEC 61000). And also this guy that is used in a lot of little motor appliance do not use snubber: MICROCHIP AN2184. I could document other application notes and several real project schematic. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly the washing machine neither uses the MOC3021.

Comment: Does this happen at any control angle?

Comment: I'm trying at low velocity (high angle) and the issue is more visible due to the difference when the (main or optocoupler) triac have unintended ON giving the entire waveform to the load. I have to try at higher velocity. It seems I have solved with a snubber, but I would avoid it due to the dimension of the components and the cost. And because real applications don't use them! Maybe I have to use the trick to anticipate the gate fire compared to the zero crossing measured.